# Birthday calendar notification

Tags: google-calendar, notifications

When filling up [contacts in google](http://google.com/contacts/) I normally enter the birthday as well. This information is then displayed in a Read-Only-Calendar in [Google-Calendar](http://google.com/cl2).

So far I do not see any way to get notifications on these dates. Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From all I've heard & read, this isn't possible. The only way I've got around it is by copying these auto-generated events to another calendar and then adding a notification. One advantage of this is you choose which ones you get an alert for, but of course, it's not ideal.

Comment: It's not ideal.. but on the other hand.. birthdays are not changing that often... so it's one time thing anyways :) But still not ideal... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can set up [birthday reminders in Google Contacts](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/12732221?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1#zippy=%2Ccreate-reminders-for-specific-dates). (https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/12732221?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1#zippy=%2Ccreate-reminders-for-specific-dates)

At the moment, this feature only seems to be available on Android devices, but it's developing rapidly (there have been some significant improvements in the last few months), so it might be worth checking for updates.