# Birthday reminders for Google Contacts?

Tags: google-contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Birthday calendar notification](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/birthday-calendar-notification)

Is there any way to set up birthday reminders in Google Contacts?

I have all the birthday's entered in for each contact, which creates a "Contacts' birthdays and events" calendar that contains the birthdays. I don't want to have to recreate these events just to get notifications for them.

I have set up my contacts to sync with my iPhone, so I'm looking for a solution that is compatible with this as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/birthday-calendar-notification

Answer (score 0):

It seems that getting notifications for read-only calendars (like your "Contacts' birthdays and events" Interesting Calendar) is not possible at this time. One option would be to use the Google Calendar gadget in gmail and list birthdays there, but I'm not sure that will work on your iPhone.