# Are Google Calendar and Contacts linked?

Tags: google-calendar, google-contacts

Can I create an event from contact with one click?

For instance to create an event as a birthday reminder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set up a birthday for a contact, you can see it in your Google Calendar by showing the birthday calendar.

To enable the birthday calendar, do the following:

1. **Settings** > **Calendar Settings**
2. Choose the **Calendars** tab
3. **Browse interesting calendars >>**
4. Choose the **More** tab
5. Select **Subscribe** on the **Contacts' birthdays and events** calendar.

Now whenever you add a birthday to a contact, you should see it in your calendar.

Comment: thank you, working nicely .. buuuut. What I do about birthday event is that I setup email reminder for about 1 or 2 weeks prior the actual birthday. Can I do that now? I am happy to have for every single birthday like that.

Comment: @Radek: I asked the same question, see: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/birthday-reminders-for-google-contacts